# Post data is not being recieved

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, post, request

I am trying to test my newly written api to send messages. It catches a message and sends it to a database. I am using https://apitester.com/ to test it. When I try to read `req.body`, I get `undefined`.

SERVER

```
    app.route('/message')
        .post(createMessage);
    var createMessage = (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body)
        var newMessage = new Message(req.body)
        mlab.insertDocument({database:'databasename', collectionName:'collectionname', documents:newMessage.getCreatePack()})
            .then(result =>  {
                res.json(result)
            })
    }
```

When I try to log(req.body), I get undefined
This is the request data. Any help is appreciated
[image: This is the request]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I need body parsing middleware, such as `body-parser`.